# Uglifyjs Invalid option CacheKeys and minify

Tags: uglifyjs, webpack-4

Is there a reason for this options to be not available in UglifyJs plugin. I am following documenation as per https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/ **

> ValidationError: UglifyJs Plugin Invalid Options
>
> options['ecma'] is an invalid additional property 
>   options['cacheKeys'] is an invalid additional property 
>   options['minify'] is an invalid additional property

package.json

```
"terser": "^3.8.1",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
"webpack": "^4.16.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.3"
```

webpack.config

```
minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        // Uncomment lines below for cache invalidation correctly
        ecma:6,
        cache: true,
        cacheKeys:(defaultCacheKeys,file) =>{
          return Object.assign(
            {},
            defaultCacheKeys,
            { terser: require('terser/package.json').version },
          );
        },
        minify:(file, sourceMap) => {
          // https://github.com/fabiosantoscode/terser#minify-options
          const terserOptions = { parse: {
                                        // parse options
                                    },
                                    compress: {
                                        // compress options
                                        "ecma": 6
                                    },
                                    mangle: {
                                        // mangle options

                                        properties: {
                                            // mangle property options
                                        }
                                    },
                                    output: {
                                        // output options
                                    },
                                    sourceMap: {
                                        // source map options
                                    },
                                    ecma: 5, // specify one of: 5, 6, 7 or 8
                                    keep_classnames: false,
                                    keep_fnames: false,
                                    ie8: false,
                                    module: false,
                                    nameCache: null, // or specify a name cache object
                                    safari10: false,
                                    toplevel: false,
                                    warnings: false };

          if (sourceMap) {
            terserOption.sourceMap = {
              content: sourceMap,
            };
          }

          return require('terser').minify(file, terserOptions);
        }
      })
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**new UglifyJsPlugin** expect a object with key **uglifyOptions** which the missing here. Please update webpack config as per below.

```
[
  new UglifyJsPlugin({
    uglifyOptions: {
      ecma: 8,
      ...
    }
  })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My mistake was that i didn't follow the naming rule in symfony.

```
assetic:
    filters:
        uglifyjs:
            # the path to the uglifyjs executable
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
```

I solved by changing the filter alias from uglifyjs to uglifyjs2

```
assetic:
    filters:
        uglifyjs2:
            # the path to the uglifyjs executable
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
```